# Generator returns undefined for a value while waiting on promise to resolve

Tags: javascript, generator, promise

I have a function connectImpl referenced in multiple places.  I am trying to invoke this promise and return its value out to the calling function synchronously through intermediating via a generator.  If I call .next() on the generator it is returned in a pending state

```
{ value: { state: 'pending' }, done: false }
```

I would like to wait on the value of this generator until it is no longer pending.  I have tried multiple versions of waitOn to accomplish this, but I cannot seem to make it work properly.

I am open to implementation suggestions.  This is driving me a bit batty. Surprisingly the final  created log of the promise fires later in the execution chain  - after the generator is done.  I am obviously missing something:

```
let models = null ;
let connectImpl = function() {
    console.log('connectImpl')
    let orm = setupImpl()
    let config = getConfigImpl()
    let qInitialize = q.nbind(orm.initialize, orm)
    if(models) {
        console.log('connectImpl:cached')
        return q(models)
    } else {
        console.log('connectImpl:create')
        return qInitialize(config).then(function(m){
            console.log('connectImpl:created')
            models = m
            return models
        })
    }
}

let waitOn = function(generator){
    console.log('waitOn')
    let done = false ;
    let generatorValue = null
    while(!done){
        var generatorResult = generator.next()
        console.log(generatorResult)
        done = generatorResult.done
        generatorValue = generatorResult.value
    }
    return generatorValue
}

let domainImpl = function() {
    console.log('domainImpl')
    let getConnection = function *() {
        console.log('domainImpl:getConnection')
        yield connectImpl()
    }

    var generator = getConnection()
    return waitOn(generator)
}

console.log('START')
console.log(domainImpl())
console.log('END')
```

I am able to invoke and get the

```
START
domainImpl
waitOn
domainImpl:getConnection
connectImpl
connectImpl:create
{ value: { state: 'pending' }, done: false }
{ value: undefined, done: true }
undefined
END
connectImpl:created
```

I am able to add execute the connectImpl promise to work with the middleware via this function - but I can't seem to adapt this to my above use case:

```
let domainMiddlewareImpl = function () {
    return function *(next) {
        let models = yield connectImpl()
        this.request.models = models.collections;
        this.request.connections = models.connections;
        yield next
    };
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks fun. Let's see how we can yield promises. Our end goal is to write something like:

```
waitOn(function*(){
    console.log("hello");
    yield Q.delay(2000); // a placeholder, your calls in your example
    console.log("World"); // this should run two seconds late.
});
```

Your issue here is that you're yielding them without waiting for them in advance. First of all, you can skip to the end for a 'ready' solution (don't!) and [here is a fiddle](http://www.es6fiddle.net/hz1o2jh0/) of what we're making. Let's go through implementing waitOn with generators:

Let's start:

```
function waitOn(gen){

}
```

So, our function takes a generator, the first thing we'll have to do is invoke it since we need to execute the generator to get its results:

```
function waitOn(gen){
    let sequence = gen(); // call the generator
}
```

Next, we'll want to wrap everything in a Promise since our `waitOn` will yield promises and return a promise for being done itself:

```
function waitOn(gen){
    let sequence = gen(); // call the generator
    return Promise.resolve(); // this is Q.resolve with Q
}
```

Now, what cases do we have:

- The generator is done and returned a value - that is a `return`
- The generator yielded a regular value and we do not have to wait for it
- The generator yielded a promise and we have to wait for it. We also have to deal with exceptions (what if we yield a promise that rejects?)

So our basic structure is something like:

```
function waitOn(gen){
    let sequence = gen(); // call the generator
    return Promise.resolve().then(function cont(value){
        let {value, done} = en.next(value); // get the next item
        // depending on the case do what's appropriate
    });
}
```

Note the destructuring assignment - I assume that's ok since your code has ES6 statements in it too. Note since this is the first call, `value` is undefined but generally we'll want to pass the value from our last call on. Now to handle the cases:

```
function waitOn(gen){
    let sequence = gen(); // call the generator
    return Promise.resolve().then(function cont(value){
        let {done, value} = en.next(value); // get the next item
        if(done) return value; // return case
        if(!value || !value.then) return cont(value); // value case, recurse
        return value.catch(e => gen.throw(e)).then(cont); // promise case 
    });
}
```

Note the `.catch` clause - we're throwing our code from the promise back to the generator for it to handle so we can try/catch the promises.

That's it! In 9 lines of JavaScript we've implemented generators for promises. Now to your code, you can yield any promise:

```
let conn =  q.nBind(orm.initialize, orm);
waitOn(function*(){
    console.log("Starting")
    let handle = yield conn(config);
    console.log("Handle created!", handle); // connected here
});
```

Happy coding and enjoy the power of coroutines. After we've had our fun - it's worth mentioning that Q already ships with `Q.async` and other newer promise libraries like Bluebird ship with their own (Bluebird has `Promise.coroutine`). If you're using a promise library - you can utilise those. This implementation works with native promises too.

Comment: Awesome answer.  I am already using q, but was unaware of the q.async - looking at that now

Comment: It looks as though the q.async takes a generator and converts it to be something promise compatible.  Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Yes, look at the usage examples